# ITKO LISA-Service Virtualization-Tutorials

Tags: automated-testing, tools

We have planned to implement ITKO LISA as a service virtualization tool for creating mock enviroments for testing.What I found lagging is there are no materials for studying/training resources.Is there anyone who can recommend free/proprietary training for this tool,since this is going to be a critical thing to do as part of our testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should contact the folks at http://www.itko.com/services/educational_services.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Here an overview over the courses provided by CA.

http://www.ca.com/us/~/media/Files/LearningPaths/ca-lisa.pdf

[image]